# VBA String as commandtext (string with no Quotes)

Tags: vba, string, quotes

I have a Sub which has a parameter string and will include it in a commandtext. My problem is that the execution does not accept a string (because of the quotes) in the command line. Is it possible to equals a commandtext to a string and make the system don't considerate the quotes? Thank you

```
Public Sub CreatView(ByVal NomeView As String)
NomeView ="View1" 'example

Dim Com As String
Dim Comando As Command
Set Comando = New Command
Com = "StringView_123.Value"
Com = Replace(Com, "123", NomeView)
Comando.CommandText = Com 'Don't work
Comando.CommandText = StringView_View1.Value 'Work fine

Aplicacao.BSO.DSO.BDAPL.Execute (Comando.CommandText)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced "commandtext" with a CallByName, my fight was in "value" (it was poorly positioned).

```
Public Sub CreatView(ByVal NomeView As String)
NomeView ="View1" 'example

Dim Com As String
Com = "StringView_123"
Com = Replace(Com, "123", NomeView)
Aplicacao.BSO.DSO.BDAPL.Execute (CallByName(Me, Com, VbMethod).Value)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

These are string variables (NomeView, Com):

`NomeView ="View1"
Com = "StringView_123.Value"`

This is a string property (CommandText is a text property of the Comando object):

`Comando.CommandText = Com`

`StringView_123` looks like the name of a control (possibly a textbox?) and it has a `Value` property.

It looks like these lines need to change:

`Com = "StringView_123.Value"
Com = Replace(Com, "123", NomeView)`

to:

`Com = StringView_123.Value
Com = Replace(Com, "123", NomeView)`

The quotes you have around the control name & property mean that you're working with a string value ("StringView_123.Value"), not the name of the control (StringView_123)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. but that part is just fine. my problem is in Aplicacao.BSO.DSO.BDAPL.Execute (Comando.CommandText) I Need it to be Aplicacao.BSO.DSO.BDAPL.Execute (StringView_View1.Value) in order to work and I just get Aplicacao.BSO.DSO.BDAPL.Execute ("StringView_View1.Value"). How do I take out the quotes?!  thak you a lot any away.

Comment: Yes, because your CommandText is referencing the name of a control (`"StringView_123.Value"`), not SQL that it can execute (`Replace(StringView_123.Value, "123", NomeView)`).  Note the quotes (or lack of them) when I'm referring to the control `StringView_123`)

Comment: Hello again. Thank you for your time and pacience. I understand what you mean and agree with it. But my control "string..." is a funcion which return a  text. If I take out the quotes, I have two problems: first the funcion name must be real, which I don't care at that time; then it makes my  Com value equals with that first function return value, which I don't want either. Because what I want with this is have a dynamic function name, and consequent execution. I tried CALLBYNAME, CALL or RUN but neither seems to work. I turned around with a case where. but I hate that solution.Thank you again